# Use the Euclid's Algorithm to find the value of $[23]^{-1}$ and $[42]^{-1}$ in ($\mathbb{Z}/73\mathbb{Z}) \setminus \{0\}, *$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I should use the Euclid's Algorithm to find the value of $[23]^{-1}$ and $[42]^{-1}$ in ($\mathbb{Z/73Z \setminus \{0\}, *}$). But I do not even know what I have to do to find the value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hints:** Using the EA, you should get $54$ and $40$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Euclidean algorithm, we get
$$73=3\cdot 23+4$$
$$23=5\cdot 4+3$$
$$4=1\cdot 3+1$$
$$3=3\cdot 1+0.$$
So, the $\operatorname{gcd}(23,73)=1$ (as expected). Now, we reverse-insert these equations to get
$$\operatorname{gcd}(23,73)=1=23\cdot(-19) + 73\cdot6.$$
So, $\operatorname{mod} 73$ the last equation states that $-19\equiv 54 (\operatorname{mod}73)$ is the inverse of $23$ in $\mathbb{Z}/73\mathbb{Z}.$
The case with $42$ is left to you :)

Edit: So, with $f$ and $g$ being your numbers 73 and 23, the Euclidean Algorithm has the structure
$$f=a_0 g+r_0$$
$$g=a_1r_0 + r_1$$
$$r_0=a_2r_1+r_2$$
$$r_1=a_3r_2+r_3$$
Since $r_3=0$ we have $\operatorname{gcd}(f,g)=1$.
Now,
$$\operatorname{gcd}(f,g)=r_2=1=r_0-r_1a_2=r_0-(g-r_0a_1)a_2=(f-ga_0)-(g_2-(f-a_0g)a_1)a_2=f(1+a_1a_2) + g(-a_0-a_2-a_0a_1a_2)$$ where $a_0=3,a_1=5,a_2=1$ and $a_3=3.$
I hope that makes sense to you now.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what you did in the last step? $\operatorname{gcd}(23,73)=1=23\cdot(-19) + 73\cdot6.$

Comment: I know how to find the gcd of two numbers. The gcd of 42 is also 1. But how do yo get the values for $b_1$ and $b_2$

Comment: I understand it. Thanks! The term "The Extended Euclidean algorithm" would have helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since $23$ is coprime with $73$, there exist $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ with 
$$
23a+73b=1.
$$
This tells you that $[23][a]=1$ in $\mathbb Z_{73}$. So now you have to use the Euclidean Algorithm to find $a$.

The situation for $42$ is exactly the same.

Comment: [73] = [3][23]+[4], [23] = [5][4]+[3], [4] = [3]+[1]. [3] = [1][3], [3] = [3].. Is this the correct procedure? What is my solution?

Comment: I dont see that there are anything in this answer that wasn't in the OP.  The OP knows he has to use the Eucledean algorithm but doesn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

$73 = 3*23+ 4$ so $\color{blue}{4} = 73 - 3*23$

$23 = 5*\color{blue}{4} + 3$ so $\color{green}{3} = 23 - 5*\color{blue}{4}$

$\color{blue}{4} = \color{green}{3}+1$

SO....

$1= \color{blue}{4} - \color{green}{3}$

$=(73 - 3*23)-(23 - 5*\color{blue}{4})$

$=(73 - 3*23)-(23 - 5*(73 - 3*23))$

$=73*6-23*19$

Which means that $23*(-19) = 1 - 7*6$ which means $23*(-19)\equiv 1 \mod 73$

Which meand $23^{-1} \equiv -19 \equiv 54 \mod 73$.

There are easier ways to do notation and keep track of progress but that is the idea.  If we kept track as we went along.

$73 = 42 + 31$ so  $\color{blue}{31} = 73 - 42$.

$42 = \color{blue}{31} + 11$

so $\color{green}{11} = 42 - \color{blue}{31}$

$= 42 - (73 - 42)$

$= 2*42 - 73$

And $\color{blue}{31} = 2*\color{green}{11} + 9$

So $\color{orange}9 = \color{blue}{31}- 2*\color{green}{11}$

$=(73 - 42) - 2(2*42 - 73)$

$=3*73-5*42$

And $\color{green}{11} = \color{orange}9 + 2$ so

$\color{purple}2 = \color{green}{11}-\color{orange}9$

$= (2*42 - 73) - (3*73-5*42)$

$= 7*42 - 4*73$

And $\color{orange}9 = 4*\color{purple}2+1$

so finally

$1 = \color{orange}9 - 4*\color{purple}2$

$=(3*73-5*42) - 4*(7*42 - 4*73)$

$=19*73 - 33*42$.

So $1 = 19*73 - 33*42$ so

$42(-33) = 1 - 19*73$

So $42(-33) \equiv 1 \mod 73$

So $42^{-1} \equiv -33\equiv 40 \mod 73$.

Answer (score 0):

A good, structural way to cover the question is to search for the 
[continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for the rational number
$$\frac {73}{23}\ ,$$
associated to / extracted from the linear diophantian equation $23a+73b=1$, $a,b\in \Bbb Z$. For this we compute by successive divisions with rest:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac {73}{23}
&=
3+\frac 4{23}
=
3+\frac 1{\frac {23}4}
=
3+\frac 1{5+\frac 34}
=
3+\frac 1{5+\frac 1{\frac 43}}
\\
&=
\boxed 3+\frac 1{\boxed 5+\frac 1{\boxed 1+\frac 1{\boxed 3}}}
\\
&=[3,5,1,3]
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, to the representation above, there is a (finite) sequence of convergents, which are the following rational numbers, that approximate "better and better" $73/23$, with denominators up to the ones computed for the convergents, 
$$
\begin{aligned}{}
[3]&=3\ ,\\
[3,5]&=3+\frac 15=\frac {16}5\ ,\\
[3,5,1]&=3+\frac 1{5+\frac 11}=\frac {19}6\ ,\\
[3,5,1,3]&=\dots=\frac{73}{23}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now let us consider the last two convergents, and their difference:
$$
\frac{73}{23}
-
\frac {19}6
=
\frac {73\cdot 6-19\cdot 23}{23\cdot 6}\ .
$$
The nummerator is "always" $\pm 1$, (the moral is that we get "best approximation" with previous convergent value,) and this leads to a solution to the diophantian problem we started with.

---

Computer support for the calculations, [sage](http://www.sagemath.org) here:

```
sage: a = 73/23
sage: convergents(a)
[3, 16/5, 19/6, 73/23]
sage: 73*6 - 19*23
1
sage: b = 73/42
sage: convergents(b)
[1, 2, 5/3, 7/4, 33/19, 73/42]
sage: 73*19 - 33*42
1
sage: F = GF(73)
sage: 1 / F(23)
54
sage: 1 / F(42)
40
```

(Note that from $73\cdot 6 - 19\cdot 23=1$, passing to modulo $73$ we get $(-19)\cdot 23=1$ mod $73$, so $-19\equiv (73-19)=54$ is the inverse of $23$ in the field with $73$ elements.